# Why is jQuery syntax used here?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As in this screencast ( http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0uZIljjElo ), I think I often see jQuery syntax being used to wrap and define functions that don't benefit from jQuery.  E.g.:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    // some code to run at load time
  });
</script>
```

It would be shorter to write the code without the 2nd and 4th lines.  Is there some value in writing after this fashion?

Comment: Without, it will run immediately, when DOM elements aren't available yet. jQuery makes sure that code between `$(function() {...})` is only executed after they *are* available, thus you can access them from within the function.

Comment: jQuery doesn't check if the elements are availble, only that the DOM is ready for scripting. If the elements are loaded some other way, jQuery wont wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement is a document ready statement, which is basically saying "Please don't run any of the code inside this block until the DOM is ready to be manipulated."

Comment: If it's the case that it will only execute on `ready` for `document`, then why does the notation `$(document).ready(function(){...});` exist at all? Why not drop the `$(document).ready` part all the time?

Comment: You are correct: `$(document).ready(function() {` is identical to `$(function() {`. The latter is just shorthand that not everyone uses or knows about.

Answer (score 7):

The code is "benefiting from jQuery" by asking the library not to run it until the entire DOM is ready. For example, if that code is in the `<head>`, references to the DOM (by "id" or "class" or anything else) generally won't work because the body has not been loaded, and so there are no elements to find.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the function is not using JQuery explicitly, it will be executed on the `ready` event of the `document`. The same effect could be achieved by using `window.onload = function() {}` but JQuery's version is better IMHO, because it allows for an arbitrary amount of functions to listen to the `ready` event.

Comment: If it's the case that it will only execute on `ready` for `document`, then why does the notation `$(document).ready(function(){...});` exist at all?  Why not drop the `$(document).ready` part?

Comment: You are correct: `$(document).ready(function() {` is identical to `$(function() {`. The latter is just shorthand that not everyone uses or knows about.

Comment: Strictly, onload listeners should be on the body element, not window. There are, of course, many ways to set multiple onload listeners without jQuery, including using addEventListener/attachEvent.

Answer (score 0):

Well nothing wrong with that only in certain cases you might want to use functions as soon as DOM object you are looking for is there so we leave function outside and use "on*" events asap. But wrapping it in jquery all DOM ready function is just a safer way to write.